# How to find OS of an EC2 instance using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can you find out the OS running on an EC2 instance using AWS CLI.

The `ec2 describe-instance` command spits out a lot of information , but there is nothing indicating the OS .

I also tried `ec2 describe-images` on a specific image. Again, there doesn't seem to be any indication of OS.

Help..?

Comment: Short answer, No, you can't do that using AWS-CLI.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer : Fair enough. I guess I better start enforcing a naming convention on the AMIs

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick way to list the Platform field, which at least distinguishes between Windows and Linux:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Platform]' --output text
i-78b4ef47  windows
i-b8ae3386  windows
i-9d3611a2  None
i-1c57c651  windows
i-a241ec91  None
i-7d26b630  None
```

Comment: What does *None* mean?

Comment: `None` is the Python equivalent to NULL. In the case of the Platform field, only Windows instances return a value (`windows`). All others do not return a value, hence `None`. (I have no idea why this is the case, but that is the behaviour.)

Comment: @EjazKarim Please start a new Question rather than adding comments to old Questions.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].ImageId' --output text) --query 'Images[0].Name'
```

$() part gets the ImageId using InstanceId.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a System Manager agent install on your instances you can use [DescribeInstanceInformation API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceInformation.html) to find that information:

```
$ aws ssm describe-instance-information --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[InstanceId,PlatformType,PlatformName]' --output text | sort

i-016073859e4b31111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-01fa3efe71e4b1111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-03d437d24f7341111 Windows Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
i-048fa3ba0aa151111 Windows Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
i-05e27c562eb881111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-09283c3c05d551111 Windows Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
i-0a51eb40351911111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-0a5aeab8f56ba1111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-0a61968dc51ba1111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-0a84d5b23e5251111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-0b057729594791111 Windows Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
i-0b1d0a7fb339b1111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-0da2fefde50351111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
i-0eafb22a9581a1111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
```

Comment: How to install this System Manager Agent? if I hit the above command, it doesn't anything.

Comment: @ReemaParakh Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-install-ssm-agent.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't query the specific OS of the instance from the AWS cli but you can query the AMI that the instance is based off of. Also, you can't get an 'OS' attribute but you can get the `Description` or `Name` of the AMI, so if you create your AMIs with a meaningful description you can make it work.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids "ami-xxxxxxxx"
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "VirtualizationType": "paravirtual", 
            "Name": "amazon-linux-20130509", 
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "amazon-linux-20130509", 
                    "Key": "Name"
                }
            ], 
            "Hypervisor": "xen", 
            "ImageId": "ami-xxxxxxxx", 
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs", 
            "State": "available", 
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1", 
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true, 
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-xxxxxxxx", 
                        "VolumeSize": 100, 
                        "VolumeType": "standard"
                    }
                }
            ], 
            "Architecture": "x86_64", 
            "ImageLocation": "123456789012/amazon-linux-20130509", 
            "KernelId": "aki-fc37bacc", 
            "OwnerId": "123456789012", 
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1", 
            "Public": false, 
            "ImageType": "machine", 
            "Description": "Amazon Linux"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to get more detailed you can always write your own script to ssh into the machines and run `cat /etc/issue` in each one of them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, while I was going to go with the Description in the AMI, it doesn't help that only some users in my org are naming them appropriately.

As for script to cat /etc/issue, I actually need the OS info to automate connecting to several EC2 instances, some running Amazon Linux (default ssh user: ec2-user) and some running RHEL (default ssh user : root) .

Comment: Exactly, that is where Ansible (or Puppet, Chef etc) comes handy to carry out these kind of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a System manager agent installed on your instances then you can get OS details and platform version with

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[InstanceId,PlatformName,PlatformVersion]' --output text | sort
```

Comment: This is the exact copy of answer provided by "Seyeong Jeong" above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @John Rotenstein answer:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,PlatformDetails]' --output text
```

The difference here is `PlatformDetails`:

```
i-01520855c048a1111     Windows
i-03ea279dd83851111     Linux/UNIX
i-091f7c7a4164f1111     Linux/UNIX
...
```

Comment: This returns None for linux instances.

Comment: @TusharTarkas strange, I just tested it again. Still works using the command. My CLI:```aws-cli/2.9.6 Python/3.11.0 Darwin/21.6.0 source/x86_64 prompt/off```

Comment: Let me check as this seems to be a different command

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to get the OS details using aws cli command "aws ec2 describe-instances". Of course, from SSM query you can get the same, but "PlatformDetails" parameter can give you the details

Type aws ec2 describe-instances --profile $PROFILE --region $REGION --instance-ids "$instance_id" --query 'Reservations[ ].Instances[ ].PlatformDetails' --output text

Replace the $PROFILE with your local aws profile, $ REGION with the Region name, and $instance_id with the id of the ec2 instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).