# How do I find all Linux EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can use the following to list all Amazon Windows EC2 instances. How do I list Linux instances?

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self amazon --filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" "Name=platform,Values!=windows"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find OS of an EC2 instance using AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950823/how-to-find-os-of-an-ec2-instance-using-aws-cli)

Comment: thank you... this is helpful...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the below to list all instances with platform type, then filter by platform type.

```
   for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f2|awk -F. '{print $2}'`; do echo -e "\nInstances in: '$region':"; aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Platform]' --output text --region $region; done;
```

Platform type "None" indicates the Linux.