# How do I find the OS of a running EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I looked at attributes of the EC2 instance, but did not get a clear attribute value that identifies the same.

I also, saw the following discussion, but Im wondering whether identifying the os/platform has been simplified by aws since this disscusion.
[How to find OS of an EC2 instance using AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950823/how-to-find-os-of-an-ec2-instance-using-aws-clia)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check through console by following procedure.

**Select instance** => **Action** => **Instance setting** => **Get instance screenshot** .

this will show the OS of your instance.

[image: Image of the instructions]

Comment: Select your instance => Action => Instance setting => Get instance screenshot . Do refresh the Screenshot and it will show the actual OS

Comment: Thanks Katha! That helped.

Comment: Also note that the given EC2 instance needs to be in a running state

Comment: This doesn't work. It only shows the lock screen.

Answer (score 47):

From Terminal inside EC2 instance: `$ cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: Came back to this question after the accepted answer is not working (flooded by logs). This underrated answer is the easiest, you don't even need to install AWS CLI for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a System Manager agent installed on your instances you can use [DescribeInstanceInformation API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstanceInformation.html) to find that information:

```
$ aws ssm describe-instance-information --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[InstanceId,PlatformType,PlatformName]' --output text --filters Key=InstanceIds,Values=i-016073859e4b31111

i-016073859e4b31111 Linux   Amazon Linux AMI
```

Comment: We utilize CloudCustodian and this helped me track down an easy way to create a policy using the aws.ssm-managed-instance.  thanks

Comment: `aws ssm describe-instance-information --query 'InstanceInformationList[*].[InstanceId,PlatformType,PlatformName]' --output text` if you want all instances

Answer (score 4):

Just run a Linux universal command `cat /etc/*se` for all OS.

Comment: A `grep '' /etc/*se` would give you also a prefix of the filename to each line, in case you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look up the `ami` which will be in the "Description" tab of the instance. However, if the `ami` is private or derived from another `ami` then you won't be able to.

You can use this if you prefer the cli:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids your_id
```

The "Platform" tag is only helpful to identify if the OS is windows(or linux if not set).

Unfortunately, there isn't a 100% accurate way to identify the OS.

AWS can easily tell you if the OS is linux or Windows but telling you what **exact** distribution you are running won't be possible without a backdoor to your machine. AWS does not implement(at least they haven't publicly admitted of doing so) backdoors to the EC2 instances.

**And even if they did** - what defines a distribution? A few simple changes to system files or headers can turn "Ubuntu" into something else, while in fact it'll still effectively be Ubuntu.

As a matter of fact, if you look at the public AMIs you can see that they do say what distribution they are based on, but as soon as you generate a new AMI based on the public one - the distribution switches to **Custom Linux**.

There's one other optiong - `nmap`. However, this is a topic of its own, it's not 100% accurate(again) and special conditions must be met. More [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html).

Comment: I tried all the options above. I'm trying to figure out whether it is a Ubuntu or Linux. So there appears to be no good option at this point. I'm surprised that this obvious need is not easily met by aws.

Comment: See - your question doesn't make much sense there "Ubuntu or Linux" - Ubuntu **is** Linux. I've updated the answer above with a little bit of information on the matter.

Comment: @ma0v, Im trying to figure out whether the ec2 instance was launched from a Linux AMI or Ubuntu AMI. This will help me decide whether to login using user 'ubuntu' or 'ec2-user'