# Get AWS machine type (ubuntu/nixos/centos, etc)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Using an AWS cli command like so:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

is there a way to get information about what kind of machine (or the AMI used) for each instance? This is the info I see for instance using `describe-instances`:

```
{
  "Monitoring": {
    "State": "disabled"
  },
  "PublicDnsName": "ecxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-238.us-xxxt-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
  "State": {
    "Code": 16,
    "Name": "running"
  },
  "EbsOptimized": false,
  "LaunchTime": "20xx-x9-21T22:59:00.000Z",
  "PublicIpAddress": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  "ProductCodes": [],
  "VpcId": "vpx-xx338d07",
  "CpuOptions": {
    "CoreCount": 2,
    "ThreadsPerCore": 1
  },
  "StateTransitionReason": "",
  "InstanceId": "i-xxxxf9762a4140a88",
  "EnaSupport": true,
  "ImageId": "amx-xx32ec5bc225539f5",
  "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-xxxt-2.compute.internal",
  "KeyName": "ntrs-prod",
  "SecurityGroups": [
    {
      "GroupName": "public web server",
      "GroupId": "sg-xxxac430acd613381"
    }
  ],
  "ClientToken": "",
  "SubnetId": "suxxxx-cc1c0e84",
  "InstanceType": "t2.medium",
  "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
    "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
  },
  "NetworkInterfaces": [
    {
      "Status": "in-use",
      "MacAddress": "0z:5O:8z:O5:3o:9z",
      "SourceDestCheck": true,
      "VpcId": "vpx-xx338d07",
      "Description": "",
      "NetworkInterfaceId": "enx-xxbd4b3bd8f339aaf",
      "PrivateIpAddresses": [
        {
          "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-xxxt-2.compute.internal",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
          "Primary": true,
          "Association": {
            "PublicIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            "PublicDnsName": "ecxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-238.us-xxxt-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
            "IpOwnerId": "amazon"
          }
        }
      ],
      "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-xxxt-2.compute.internal",
      "Attachment": {
        "Status": "attached",
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
        "AttachmentId": "enx-xxtach-01948e0bd9059a635",
        "AttachTime": "20xx-x9-21T22:59:00.000Z"
      },
      "Groups": [
        {
          "GroupName": "public web server",
          "GroupId": "sg-xxxac430acd613381"
        }
      ],
      "Ipxxxxdresses": [],
      "OwnerId": "91xxxx820371",
      "PrivateIpAddress": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
      "SubnetId": "suxxxx-cc1c0e84",
      "Association": {
        "PublicIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
        "PublicDnsName": "ecxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-238.us-xxxt-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
        "IpOwnerId": "amazon"
      }
    }
  ],
  "SourceDestCheck": true,
  "Placement": {
    "Tenancy": "default",
    "GroupName": "",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-xxxt-2a"
  },
  "Hypervisor": "xen",
  "BlockDeviceMappings": [
    {
      "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
      "Ebs": {
        "Status": "attached",
        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
        "VolumeId": "vox-xxda51640e0c4ac9a",
        "AttachTime": "20xx-x9-21T22:59:01.000Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Architecture": "x86_64",
  "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
  "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
  "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Value": "manu-demo",
      "Key": "Name"
    },
    {
      "Value": "Web Server",
      "Key": "Type"
    }
  ],
  "HibernationOptions": {
    "Configured": false
  },
  "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in the describe-images output under the field `ImageId`.

To get a list of instances and their images (i.e. AMIs), you can use the `query` option to list only those attributes:

```sh
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId, ImageId]"
```

Comment: right so given the imageid you can look up what kind of OS

Comment: I think this thread will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950823/how-to-find-os-of-an-ec2-instance-using-aws-cli